# Counting blank spaces till next string in PHP array

Tags: php, xlsx

I have imported .xlsx file to PHP through a script. I only need two columns from the file 
[image: http://imgh.us/xlsxx.png]

This is done, but as you can see there is address and following it blank spaces.
I need the information from right column to be in one string corresponding to the address on the left.

```
foreach ($Reader as $Row)
    {
        array_push($data, $Row);
        $aadress_loc = array_search("Aadress", $Row);
        $eluruumid = array_search("Ehitise osad", $Row);
        array_push($asukohtruumid, $aadress_loc);
        array_push($asukohtruumid, $eluruumid);
    }
    $li_length = count($data);
    for ($i = 1; $i < $li_length; $i++){
        array_push($aadress_mas,($data[$i][$asukohtruumid[0]])); // left column
        array_push($ruumid_mas,($data[$i][$asukohtruumid[1]]));  // right column
    }

Array
(
[0] => Harju maakond, Kernu vald, Laitse küla, Lossi tee 6
[1] => 
[2] =>  // 0;2 is the length of the first element
)
Array
(
[0] => E/1;E/2;E/3;E/4;E/5;E/6;M/7/Kontoriruumid;E/8;E/9
[1] => E/10;E/11;E/12;E/13;E/14;E/15;E/16;E/17;E/18;E/19
[2] => E/20;E/21;E/22;E/23;E/24
so I need to merge these 0;2 elements from another array to one string 
and repeat the process with another elements from aadress array.
```

[image]

Here is the array with the diffrences but I don't       know how can I use it to do what I need.
Sorry for not so good english.

Comment: Maybe checking if the row is empty,  if(!empty($Row)) { //do something if true }

Comment: I already did this, and I have array where I have the diffrences, but I have already worked with this all night and my mind isn't working very well. Here is a picture : http://imgh.us/13123.png

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, can you explain a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understand the question but I think you are looking for this:

```
foreach ($Reader as $Row)
{
    echo $row[0].' - '.$row[7];

    // OR

    echo $row['Aadress'].' - '.$row['Ehitise osad'];
}
```

I am not sure which one will work in your situation.